# Union of two languages

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

If I have these languages:

$$\begin{align*}
S&=\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h\}\\
A&=\{b,g\}\\
B&=\{a,b,c,d,f,h\}\\
C&=\{a,c,g\}\,,
\end{align*}$$

Writing $X'$ for the complement of a set $X$, what would B'∪ C consist of? Would the elements of this language then be C = {c g}?

Also if I have B ∩ (A ∪ C'), would the elements of this language then be {ab bb cb db fb hb}? Since A ∪ C' would = {b} then combined with B we have {ab bb cb db fb hb}

Comment: This appears to be a question purely about mathematics, with no particular connection to computer science articulated, and such appears to be off-topic for this site.

Comment: This question is for a class that is not a math class. Sorry.

Comment: Please see http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/704/755.  The class where you ran into this is not super-relevant to the question of what is on-topic here.  We expect you to articulate the connection to computer science in the question.

Comment: Ok i will ask on the math exchange. Thanks. Sorry.

Comment: Please dont' re-post or cross-post, as that violates site rules.  You can flag this for moderator attention and ask them to migrate it, if you wish.

Comment: Assuming $S$ is the universe, $B'=\{e, g\}$ so $B'\cup C=\{e, g\}\cup\{a, c, g\} = \{a, c, e, g\}$. Similarly, $A\cup C'=\{b, g\}\cup\{b,d,e,f,h\}=\{b,d,e,f,g,h\}$ and so $B\cap(A\cup C')=\{a,b,c,d,f,h\}\cap\{b,d,e,f,g,h\}=\{b,d,f,h\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Union, intersection and complement have their usual meanings from set theory.